# Craft CMS only works when '/index.php/' is added

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have taken all of the steps listed by [Craft](https://craftcms.com/support/remove-index.php) to correct this.

My public/.htaccess file looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Added the following to craft/config/general.php array:

```
'omitScriptNameInUrls' => 'true',
```

I'm using Ubuntu so I modified my /etc/apache2/apache2.conf to:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I then restarted Apache2:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

And ran:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

I still need to use index.php in order to access all URLs aside from the root URL. Example: http://myUrl.com works, http://myUrl.com/index.php/api/entries.json works

Answer (score 1):

I might be completely wrong on this but have you tried changing the "AllowOverride All" in the "httpd.conf" file, I had the same issues earlier today and changing the AllowOverride from none to All in the httpd config fixed it

Comment: Please see this first how-to-answer This question is answered before, obviously, you can add your answer here. But You Need to understand some points before answering. First, don't add an answer which is previously added with the same code or suggestion. Second, don't add an overly complicated answer if the user has asked very specifically about the problem and what he needs to solve this. Third, You can add a comment if you want to suggest anything regarding the answer or question.